# TDWC dashboard for monitoring

Tags: workload-scheduler

Is it possible to create into TDWC a  blinking dashboard widget for the error list widget?

Comment: Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the scenario correctly, you would like to have widgets that blink in some specific cases, maybe when the value retrieved and showed in the widget is bigger than some kind of threshold.
Widgtes provided cannot blink but it is still possible to set several thresholds and the widget will change shape and color accordingly to the specified thresholds in order to understand at first glance every change in the dashboard.